# Remove repeating string pattern from variable with POSIX parameter expansion

Tags: shell-script, scripting, variable, posix, parameter

I wanted to use [2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to remove leading characters from a string, but was surprised to find out that "Remove Largest Prefix Pattern" doesn't automatically repeat the pattern.

```
$ x=aaaaabc
$ printf %s\\n "${x##a}"
aaaabc
```

As you can see, only the first `a` has been removed. Expected output was `bc` for any of `x=bc`, `x=abc`, `x=aabc`, `x=aaabc` or `x=aaaabc`.

I'm struggling to figure out how I have to write the pattern if I want to remove as many `a` as possible from the beginning of `$x`. I had no luck searching for other threads either, because many answers use bash, but I'm looking for a POSIX shell solution.

Comment: For other readers, the bash solution is: `shopt -s extglob; printf '%s\n' "${x##+(a)}"` -- ref [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don’t think you can do this in a generic fashion (*i.e.* ignoring specific features of the pattern), using only POSIX shell constructs, without using a loop:

```
until [ "${x#a}" = "$x" ]; do x="${x#a}"; done
```

Answer (score 9):

For certain patterns you might be able to "reverse" the pattern by matching the part of the variable that you want to keep:

```
$ for x in "" a aa abc aabc aaabc aaabca aaabcabc bc bcaa
> do
>     printf %s\\n "${x#"${x%%[!a]*}"}"
> done



bc
bc
bc
bca
bcabc
bc
bcaa
```

Comment: Ah yes, keep everything starting with the first character that‘s not “a”!

Comment: For which `patterns` will this fail? Do you mean repeated multi character strings  ?

Comment: @QuartzCristal this isn't a generalized solution, so it's easier to describe the patterns where it can *succeed* than those where it can fail.  This approach only works if you can write a pattern to match the part of the string you want to keep.  In this case, you want to keep the longest possible match that starts with "not a" followed by anything (i.e. `*`).  (For cases where it can work, it's very clever, +1 from me!)

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, I understand, it is not easy to describe, and yes, +1 from me as well.  But an example of what the `certain patterns` means, I mean, where it fails, would make this answer a lot more clear.

Answer (score 5):

`a` as a pattern matches `a`, there's no way it  can match `aaa`.

While the POSIX `sh` specification is based on a subset  of the Korn shell, and the  Korn shell has `*(foo)` (matches a sequence of 0 or more `foo`s) and `+(foo)` operators (matches a sequence of one  or more `foo`s, same as `foo*(foo)`), those were not specified by POSIX as they're not backward compatible with those of the Bourne shell, and means there are a number of contexts where they  couldn't be used like in:

- `find . -name '*(x)'` which is currently required to match on filenames that end in `(x)`
- `pattern='*(x)'; case $file in ($pattern) ...; esac` or `${file##$pattern}`. Same. You'll notice that ksh88 or pdksh do not recognise those operators in those cases.

Repetition is supported in regular expressions. POSIX specifies a number of utilities that can match regular expressions (`expr`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`...). Some shells have or have had some of those builtin. `expr` was built in (or could be made builtin) the Almquist shell. `ksh93` can be built with `expr`, `grep` and `sed` builtin and can get their output without forking. Some ash-based shells can also get the output of command substitutions without forking when it's made of one invocation of a builtin command. The `busybox` shell is another example of a shell where all those utilities can be invoked without forking nor executing.

On the other hand, `printf` which you use in your question is *not* builtin in ksh88 nor most pdksh derivatives. Appart from the special builtins and builtins such as `export`/`getopts`/`read`... which can only reasonably be builtin, POSIX does not give you guarantee that a command may or may not be builtin.

So:

```
x=$( expr "x$x" : 'xa*\(.*\)' )
```

For instance could strip the leading `a`s internally in the shell. With a couple of caveats though:

- that returns with a failure exit  status if the result is an empty string or some representations of 0
- that also strips trailing newline characters.
- you'll have noticed the `x` prefix we also need to add to prevent that to fail if `$x` happens to contain an `expr` operator (see the [Application Usage section of POSIX `expr` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42_16) for more details on that).

Or with `awk`:

```
x=$(awk 'BEGIN {sub(/^a*/, "", ARGV[1]); print ARGV[1]}' "$x")
```

Or `sed`:

```
x=$(printf '%s\n' "$x" | sed '1s/^a*//')
```

(`sed` being the least appropriate here as it works line-based and need to be fed its input via stdin or a file).

Comment: Why is `x$x` needed? In which conditions could it fail?

Comment: @QuartzCristal, see edit. You can try with `x='('`, `x=+`, `x=index` with various implementations.

Comment: I see, thanks @StéphaneChazelas